# Modals with SendMail functionality not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-modal, phpmailer

I have written a web page which contains a table like this:

[RFP Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB3Oe.png)

When the user clicks on an RFP#, a modal popup will appear that will look like this:

[Modal Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB3Oe.png)

When the user has completed and submitted the form, a download link will appear wherein they may download a pdf of the RFP.

My problem is that the other modals do not function properly. The first modal works fine: after completing and submitting the form, the download button appears, and email gets sent. I'm suspecting that it may be the way I implemented the modals: I just made one modal at first, copy and paste to make several more then change the id and data-target. By the way, I'm doing this on site hosted on A2Hosting.

Here's my code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" style="text-align:center; background-color:aliceblue">
        <thead>
            <tr style="text-align:center">
                <th scope="col">RFP #</th>
                <th scope="col">Description of RFP</th>
                <th scope="col">End Date</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:700"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">RFP19-CHCC-GSS-015</a></td>
                <td><a href="#">Pest Control Services</a></td>
                <td>07/24/2019</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:700"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2">RFP19-CHCC-CGC-CCP-017</a></td>
                <td><a href="#">Crisis Counseling Program</a></td>
                <td>07/23/2019</td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- Modals Start-->

    <div id="modal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 style="text-align:center; margin-top:20px">
                        Contact Us
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form role="form" method="post" id="reused_form">
                        <p> Send your message in the form below and we will get back to you as early as possible. </p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name"> Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required maxlength="50">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email"> Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required maxlength="50">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="phone"> Phone Number:</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" required maxlength="50">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="message"> Message:</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message Here" maxlength="6000" rows="7"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" id="btnContactUs">Submit &rarr;</button>
                    </form>
                    <div id="success_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">
                        <h3>Sent your message successfully!</h3>
                        <a href="docs/RFP/test.pdf" download="RFP19.pdf">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" id="btnContactUs">Submit &rarr;</button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; "> <h3>Error</h3> Sorry there was an error sending your form. </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="modal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 style="text-align:center; margin-top:20px">
                        Contact Us
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form role="form" method="post" id="reused_form">
                        <p> Send your message in the form below and we will get back to you as early as possible. </p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name"> Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required maxlength="50">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email"> Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required maxlength="50">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="phone"> Phone Number:</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" required maxlength="50">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="message"> Message:</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message Here" maxlength="6000" rows="7"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" id="btnContactUs">Submit &rarr;</button>
                    </form>
                    <div id="success_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">
                        <h3>Sent your message successfully!</h3>
                        <a href="docs/RFP/test.pdf" download="RFP19.pdf">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" id="btnContactUs">Submit &rarr;</button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; "> <h3>Error</h3> Sorry there was an error sending your form. </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I recommend you delete this question - it's unlikely it will help anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. I did not realize that I had to change the id's of some of the modal's components.